# If $g$ and $g\circ f$ are continuous function, then $f$ is a continuous function?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, fake-proofs

Let be $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ a continuous function beetween two topological spaces and we suppose that the function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ beetween the topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ is such that its composition with $g$ is continuous: so is $f$ continuous?

If $g\circ f$ is continuous so for any open set $U$ in $Z$ it result that $(g\circ f)^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(g^{-1}(U))$ is an open set in $X$ so by the continuity of $g$ we can ovserve that the the inverse imagine by $f$ of the open set $g^{-1}(U)$ is an open set: so could I conclude that $f$ is continuous?

Howewer I doubt that if $g$ is not bijective I don't  say anything about the continuity of $f$.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if $g$ is not constant, $f$ can be discontinuous.

Take for instance $\sin(2\pi\{x\})=\sin(2\pi x)$ where $\{\cdot\}$ is fractional part.

It suffices $g$ erases discontinuities of $f$, mostly by being not injective, if $g$ takes the same values at $f(x_0^-)$ and $f(x_0^+)$ then even if $f$ not continuous at $x_0$ then $g\circ f$ will be.

We can even take $f(x)=\frac 1x$ which is way discontinuous at $0$ (infinite) and make $g\circ f$ completely flat (thus $\mathtt C^\infty$) at $0$ by composing with $g(u)=e^{-u^2}$.

*Note: that on $[0,+\infty)$ $g$ is bijective and $g\circ f$ continuous, yet $f$ still not defined in $0$.*

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider the fact that any constant function is *always* going to be continuous.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro What happens if $g$ is a constant function?

Comment: If g is costant I don't now if generally for every open set I could consider $g^{-1}(U)$ so this is a countrexample; anyway could you say a little more clearly what you mean?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Yes, sure, look at inverse images of open sets. If $g$ is a constant function, what are the possible options for $g^{-1}(U)$? Check it out for yourself, and when you have the answer, you will see clear as day that constant functions _must always_ be continuous. And once you know that, then we see that if $g$ is constant, $g\circ f$ is also constant (and therefore continuous), _no matter what $f$ is_.

Comment: Okay, but in any case a funcion is continous iff the inverse imagine of an open set is an open set.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro That is what the word "continuous" is defined to mean, yes.

Comment: Okay, so it seems the proof is wrong; but what can be said about the assertion?

Comment: Assume, as suggested, that $g$ is a constant function. Can you come up with a counter example $f$?